# Delete a record from table if its date of joining completed six month

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete a record from table if the field joindate is six months old or older.

Suppose An employee's joindate date is 15-06-2018 and on 15-11-2018 the user should be deleted

I have stored joindate and datetime. now trying to create a query that will delete a record if current date equals joindate + 6month.

Comment: So show us then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a pretty simple expression.

```
joindate < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -6 MONTH
```

take current date, subtract 6 months from it, and then compare to the joindate column, to find out if joindate is earlier.

We can test that in a query:

```
SELECT t.joindate < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -6 MONTH `older_than_six_months`
     , t.joindate 
     , t.id
     , ... 
  FROM mytable t
 ORDER BY t.joindate ASC
```

The expression will return 1 (true) if joindate is earlier than six months, or return 0 (false) or NULL.

We can specify a specific date value in place of `DATE(NOW())` for testing

```
SELECT t.joindate < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -6 MONTH `older_than_six_months`
     , t.joindate < '2018-07-01' + INTERVAL -6 MONTH `six_months_20180701`
     , t.joindate 
     , t.id
     , ... 
  FROM mytable t
 ORDER BY t.joindate ASC
```

Once we have an expression that is tested, we can use it in a DELETE statement

```
DELETE t.*
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.joindate < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -6 MONTH
```

(Personally, I would do the less than or less than or equal comparison test `<` or `<=` rather than an equals test.)